# How to get Http Status Code from Exception

Tags: c#

using middleware to handle the exception .net Core with this link:
[How to return the same status code from a second API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977967/how-to-return-the-same-status-code-from-a-second-api-call)
got stuck on how to get status code from Exception. Specifically this:  ConvertExceptionToHttpStatusCode

Comment: The mentioned SO answer did not give the code for the function  ConvertExceptionToHttpStatusCode, if you add a comment there, that author of the answer could clarify. Ah, I see you are new to SO and don't have commenting privilege yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get StatusCode from HttpRequestException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217619/how-do-i-get-statuscode-from-httprequestexception)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.